# Delphi Firemonkey TGrid how to update

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tgrid

I have a TGrid with a mixture of columns (ImageColumn and StringColumn).  I can populate it using onGetValue event which works fine. My questions are:

1. How to force the entire grid to rebuild and cause onGetValue event?
   I'm using UpdateStyle at the monent.
2. How can I update a single cell in the grid?

Answer (score 6):

The grid updates only visible cells! `Grid1.UpdateStyle` force the grid to rebuild and is causing `onGetValue` events but its slow. `Grid1.ReAlign` is much faster.

As soon as cells become visible, they will be updated.

Updating 1 cell:

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateCell(col, row: integer);
var
  cell: TStyledControl;
begin
  cell := Grid1.Columns[col].CellControlByRow(row);
  if Assigned(cell) then
    cell.Data := 'Note: use the same datasource as OnGetValue';
end;
```

cell is not assigned when row never become visible.

Answer (score 6):

The other option is to call `Grid1.beginUpdate;` make your changes and then call `Grid1.endupdate;` which will cause the visible grid to recalculate and redraw.